# Behaviour of AjaxEditableLabel and Validator confuses me

Tags: java, wicket

i searched a lot for this problem but no explanation explains what i am searching for

i have a class like i posted at the end. In very short: The behaviour of PatternValidation is different to manual validation.

For example: 
The AjaxEditableLabel has a Label and an Editor, which switches for editing (focussing) and for Cancel or Submit

If i do an input which is unvalid for the Patternvalidator, the input is marked an you can correct it. If you then press Esc the editor is set invisible and the label is again empty. But if i edit the label again, the value is still in the editor, this is wrong.

If i do an input which passes the Patternvalidator, but is unvalid inside of the onSubmit method, the input is marked also an you can correct it also. But if you than press Esc the typed value is written in the label and this should not be. And i really need the further validation inside the onSubmit.

It seems like something between the Validation part an the onSubmit() Method pulls the value from the Editor to the Label. Do i have something completely wrong in my mind?

Some example code:

```
public class MyEditableLabel extends AjaxEditableLabel<String>{
    public MyEditableLabel(String id, IModel<String> model) {
        super(id, model);
        PatternValidator patternValidator = new PatternValidator(Pattern.compile(
            "(^([0-9]|[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$)|((\\d{1,2})(,|\\.)(\\d\\d))"));
        this.add(patternValidator);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // further validation
        if( editorValue.equals("00:00") ) { //just for example
            onError(target);
        } else {
            super.onSubmit(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in AjaxEditableLabel, it will be fixed in the next Wicket release.

For now you can override onCancel():

```
protected void onCancel(final AjaxRequestTarget target)
{
    super.onCancel();
    getEditor().clearInput();
}
```

Comment: ah this i really nice, helped me a lot. this fixes the first wrong behaviour. thx